# Why is reCAPTCHA sometimes really easy and sometimes really hard?

Tags: recaptcha

Sometimes reCAPTCHA asks you to identify a slightly crooked number and a Google Street View scanned street number. Other times, it's mixed-case, barely legible text.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Related: http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/05/the-trouble-it-takes-these-days-to.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason for that. One of the words is already known by the machine and the other one isn't. The app is using human task force to decipher words that OCR can't. Therefore, the words are completely randomized and don't really take into account how difficult they are.

Find more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435707

Comment: But how does this explain the occasional crazy captcha?

Comment: That crazy word was supposely present in a document that ReCAPTCHA is trying to convert from image to text.